# Form Validation Works But Does Not Prevent Form Submission

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, form-submit

I use javascript to validate my form input and it works fine but the form still gets submitted when errors are not corrected.

How do I prevent form submission until the user makes corrections?

Sample Code Below;

```js
$('.validate').hide();
$('body').on('blur', '#phone', function() {
  $('.validate').hide();
  isphone($(this).val());
});

function isphone(phone) {
  if (phone === "1234" || phone === "23456") {
    $(".validate").show();

  } else {
    $(".validate").hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<form action='' method='POST' id="submitForm">

  <input type="phone" name='phone' required='' id="phone" placeholder="0000-000-0000" />

  <div class="validate"><span style="color: red;"><b>Phone in use!</b></span></div>

  <button href='/' type='submit' id="submitForm">Process</button>

</form>
```

Comment: At its simplest, you can block form submission with `$('.validate').on('submit', function(){return false})`. You might choose more complex logic in the handler 

Comment: If you don't mind, can you show me how you would place the code with my sample code above? Please?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo above. Adding an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a helpful answer, I made a small refactor, rewriting `isphone` to be a reusable validation function that just returns `true` or `false`. I renamed it too. Now we can reuse the validation logic in different places.

`form` elements emit a `submit` event just before they are actually submitted. We must listen for the `sumbit` event, and if validation fails, we can `return false` which will cancel the event, and therefore preventing form submission.

```js
$('.validate').hide();
$('body').on('blur', '#phone', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (isPhoneInUse(value)) {
    $(".validate").show();
  } else {
    $(".validate").hide();
  }
});
$('#submitForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  var value = $("#phone").val();
  if (isPhoneInUse(value)) {
    // validation failed. cancel the event
    console.log("not submitting");
    return false;
  }
})

function isPhoneInUse(phone) {
  return (phone === "1234" || phone === "23456")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<form action='' method='POST' id="submitForm">

  <input type="phone" name='phone' required='' id="phone" placeholder="0000-000-0000" />

  <div class="validate"><span style="color: red;"><b>Phone in use!</b></span></div>

  <button href='/' type='submit' id="submitForm">Process</button>

</form>
```

Comment: You are the best Bro! It worked!